Outlook 2016 migration from old laptop: How to skip creating account on first run?
I have a fresh installation of Office. Also I have a .pst  file from my old laptop .  My plan is to run Outlook 2016 and open the .pst file. Then my account will be imported from it. However, when I run Outlook it requires creating a new account.  Can I skip this and go directly  to  Outlook and use its import or File  menu? Am I wrong  about the right way of migration? Is it enough to just open the old .pst file?
OS: Windows 10  on both laptops.

The .pst doesn’t contain any of your account information. It’s an offline archive of your emails. The .pst isn’t connected to a specific account other than it contains emails sent to a specific email address

Disconnect your computer from the internet and start outlook. This will give you an option to skip account creation on first boot.
